# Cómo puedo validar la existencia de un dato en una tabla y luego poder ejecutar el insert del formulario

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, bootstrap

Por favor, quien me pueda ayudar con éste caso:

**PREGUNTA ORIGINAL**
Deseo validar si un dato que se ingresa en un input de un formulario existe en una tabla MYSQL.
Antes lograba que se ejecutara el insert que se encuentra en el codigo PHP pagina_insertar_proveedor.php; pero ahora queriendo hacer la validacion del dato RIF, no se ejecuta el insert.

Se me ocurrió hacer un form dentro de un form y por lo visto el chequeo lo hace bien, a pesar que me permite seguir ingresando otros datos.

Quiero saber si ésta es la mejor forma de hacer validaciones, dado que me parece que el llamado al codigo del insert ahora debo hacerlo tambien dentro del ajax. De ser así quisiera me indicaran cómo puedo hacerlo

Gracias

**SEGUN LA RECOMENDACION QUE ME HICIERON**

1. inhabilitar todos los input excepto el del rif
2. hacer la revision si existe el rif
3. si no existe deseo habilitar los input para seguir llenando el formulario y pasar al proceso de insercion

¿Que esta sucediendo?

1. Debo dar click en cualquier parte del form despues que coloco el rif
2. En ese momento verifica y da el mensaje si existe o no el rif
3. NO HABILITA LOS DEMAS INPUT
4. por ende no llego al punto de la insercion

**AQUI EL CODIGO DONDE SE ENCUENTRA EL FORMULARIO**

```html
<?php
    session_start();
  
  if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario_logueado"])){
    
    header('location: /form/login.php');
      
  }

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    
    <head>
    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Maestro de Proveedores</title>
        <link href="/estilo_registro_pago.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script>

          //AQUI VERIFICO SI EXISTE EL NUMERO DE RIF DE PROVEEDOR EN LA TABLA PROVEEDORES
          
          $(document).ready(function() {  
          $('#rif_prov').on('blur', function()
          {
            $('#result-rif').html('<img src="/imagenes/loader.gif"/>').fadeOut(1000);
            //var rif = $(this).val();
            var rif=$("#rif_prov").val();   
            var dataString = 'rif='+rif;            
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/php/maestros/chequear_proveedor_existente.php",
              data: dataString,
              success: function(data)
                {
                  $('#result-rif').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
                }
            });
            });              
            });
        
        </script>
    </head>
    
     <div class="form-control page-header col-md-6 mx-auto text-center">
          <!--<div class="row" col>-->
          <h4>Módulo Proveedores<small> - Registro de Proveedores </small></h4>
       </div>
      
      <div class="container">
        <!--<h2>Módulo de Registro de Cobranza</h2>-->
      <br>        
        <form action="/php/maestros/pagina_insertar_proveedor.php" name="Aceptar" method="post">            
            <div class="row">
              <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="col-md-3">          
                  <label for="rif_prov">RIF ó Cédula:</label>
                       <div class="col">
                          <input class="form-control" placeholder="RIF ó Cédula" name="rif_prov" id="rif_prov"> 
                          <p class="help-block">Introducir (J) ó (V) seguido de números, sin guión</p>                          
                       </div>
                       <div id="result-rif"></div>                       
                </div>
              </form>                            
              <div class="col-md-9">
                  <label for="Nombre">Nombre: </label>
                        <div class="col"> 
                            <input class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" required disabled>
                                
                        </div>
              </div>
            </div>
              <div class="row">                                    
                   <div class="col-md-12">      
                     <label for="direccion">Dirección</label>
                        <div class="col">
                          <textarea class="form-control" id="direccion"  placeholder="Dirección" name="direccion" required disabled></textarea>
                        </div>
                   </div>
              </div>   
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-4">      
                     <label for="estado">Estado / Provincia</label>
                        <div class="col">
                            <input class="form-control" id="estado" placeholder="Estado" name="estado" required disabled></input>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">      
                   <label for="municipio">Municipio</label>
                      <div class="col">
                          <input class="form-control" id="municipio" placeholder="Municipio" name="municipio" required disabled></input>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">      
                   <label for="sector">Sector / Urbanización / Barrio</label>
                      <div class="col">
                          <input class="form-control" id="sector" placeholder="Sector" name="sector" required disabled></input>
                      </div>
                  </div>                  
              </div>
              <div class="row">                                    
                   <div class="col-md-6">      
                     <label for="telefono">Teléfonos</label>
                        <div class="col">
                            <input class="form-control" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" name="telefono" required disabled></input>
                        </div>
                   </div>                   
                   <div class="col-md-6">      
                     <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <div class="col">
                            <input class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required disabled></input>
                        </div>
                   </div>
              </div>
              <br>
             <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-1">                 
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-md-4 col-sm-1" name="Aceptar">Aceptar </button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-md-4 col-sm-1" name="Cancelar" onClick="location.href='/index.php'">Salir   </button>
                   </div>
              </div>              
            </div>         
        </form>       
        </div>       
    </body>    
</html>
```

**AQUI EL CODIGO DONDE REALIZO LA BUSQUEDA DEL RIF**

```html
<?php
    
    if (isset($_POST)) {        
        sleep(1);
        $rif  = strip_tags($_POST['rif']);
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $path .= "/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/db/accesoDB.php";
        require_once($path);
        $pdo = AccesoDB::getConnectionPDO();            
        $stmt=$pdo->prepare("SELECT rif FROM proveedores WHERE rif=:rif");
        $stmt->execute(array(':rif'=>$rif));
        $count=$stmt->rowCount();
        sleep(1);
   if($count>0){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Rif no disponible.</strong></div>';
    } else { 
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Rif disponible!</strong></div>';
    }
}
?>
```

**AQUI EL CODIGO DONDE HAGO LA INSERCION DE LOS DATOS**

```html
<?php
    session_start();    
    if(!isset($_SESSION["usuario_logueado"])){      
        header('location: form/login.php');     
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Grabando Proveedor</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $busqueda_rif=$_POST["rif"];
    $busqueda_nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
    $busqueda_direccion=$_POST["direccion"];
    $busqueda_estado=$_POST["estado"];
    $busqueda_municipio=$_POST["municipio"];
    $busqueda_sector=$_POST["sector"];
    $busqueda_telefono=$_POST["telefono"];
    $busqueda_email=$_POST["email"];
    $fechaActual= date('Ymd');  
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/db/accesoDB.php";
    require_once($path);
    $pdo = AccesoDB::getConnectionPDO();
  try {
    
    /*$dbh=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=trinitarias', 'root', '');*/
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
    $sql="INSERT INTO proveedores (rif, nombre, direccion, estado, municipio, sector,
                                   telefonos, email, fec_ing)
                                         values
                                         (:rif,
                                         :nom,
                                         :dir,
                                         :est,
                                         :mun,
                                         :sec,
                                         :tel,
                                         :ema,
                                         :fec)";    
    $resultado=$pdo->prepare($sql);     
    $resultado->execute(array(":rif"=>$busqueda_rif,
                              ":nom"=>$busqueda_nombre,
                              ":dir"=>$busqueda_direccion,
                              ":est"=>$busqueda_estado,
                              ":mun"=>$busqueda_municipio,
                              ":sec"=>$busqueda_sector,
                              ":tel"=>$busqueda_telefono,
                              ":ema"=>$busqueda_email,
                              ":fec"=>$fechaActual));
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("PROVEEDOR NUEVO PROCESADO");
        window.location.href="/index.php";
        </script>';
    }catch(Exception $e){     
      echo "Error terminando el archivo: " . $e->getMessage();  
   }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: según lo que te entiendo es como dejar al final del llenado del formulario el chequeo con ajax, cierto?

Comment: Si tienes el `rif` desde el principio no tienes que hacer dos llamadas Ajax, simplemente: 1. Mandas todos los datos al servidor; 2. Tomas el `rif` y verificas si existe, en cuyo caso no harías la inserción devolviendo un mensaje; 3. Si no existe ejecutas la inserción.

Comment: @A.Cedano quería dar un aviso justo al perder el foco del input RIF. Por lo que le entiendo, debo dejar que se llene el formulario completo y luego hacer las validaciones respectivas al dar aceptar, cierto?

Comment: Acabas de dar un dato interesante. Y no te recomiendo esperar a que se llene todo el formulario (sería pésimo desde el punto de vista de UX esperar a llenar todo un form para luego decir al usuario que ese `rif` está repetido). En ese caso, es mejor: 1. Desactivar por defecto todos los input, menos el del `rif`; 2. Escuchar los cambios del input que recoge el `rif`, para verificar si existe; 3. Si existe desbloqueas los otros input para que el form sea llenado; 4. Envías el form. Así resuelves el problema con código adecuado también desde el punto de vista de UX.

Comment: ok @A.Cedano , voy a digerirlo paso a paso, pero entendí el proceso. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano hice un pequeño cambio y coloque el codigo modificado

Comment: Ok, pero no devuelvas un `alert` desde el servidor, eso dificulta las comprobaciones cuando el cliente recibe la respuesta. Es mejor cuando hagas la verificación del `rif`, devolver desde el servidor un json con un par `clave:valor` así más o menos:  `"existe":true` o `"existe":false` luego en el `success` de Ajax pones algo como esto: `if (!data.existe) { /*Aqui habilitas los input, incluyendo un botón Enviar para el formulario*/  } else { /*Los input siguen deshabilitados y puedes informar sobre rif repetido por un mensaje o como quieras*/ }`

Comment: El botón `Enviar` del formulario tendría su propio evento de escucha (que seria del tipo `onclick`)  y en ese bloque recogerías los datos de los `input` para enviarlos al servidor por medio de una petición Ajax diferente a aquella que verificó si el `rif` existía.

Comment: Una cosa: recuerda que una vez que llegues al PHP, vuelve a comprobar la existencia del rif, y válida como si no lo hubieras comprobado antes. Recuerda que las comprobaciones deben ser OBLIGATORIAS en backend.

Answer (score 0):

El primer error que veo es que tienes un HTML mal formado, con un formulario dentro de otro, eso no es correcto y, casi siempre, resulta en errores inesperados; además de cierres `</input>`, que no son necesarios en HTML5.

Para tener un funcionamiento más adecuado y una mejor experiencia de usuario, te sugiero:

- Asignar ID al formulario para poder acceder a sus elementos y al evento *submit*.
- Agregar un botón para validar RIF y realizar la petición AJAX cuando se haga clic en él, en lugar de cuando el campo pierda el foco.
- Al hacer clic en el botón, realiza la petición AJAX y analiza el resultado devuelto, si es cero, quiere decir que aún no está registrado, muestras mensaje y puedes continuar, activando todos los elementos, excepto RIF y el botón mismo.
- De lo contrario, muestras el mensaje de error.
- Después de realizar la inserción vuelves a poner todo como al inicio, para que se pueda insertar un nuevo registro.

**Nota:** Sería conveniente validar RIF con una expresión regular.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // En el inicio, activar solo RIF y botón Validar RIF
  activaDesactiva(true);
  // Clic en botón Validar RIF
  $('#validar-rif').on('blur', function() {
    $('#result-rif').html('<img src="/imagenes/loader.gif"/>').fadeOut(1000);
    var rif = trim($("#rif_prov").val());
    // Validar que no esté vacío
    if(rif == '') {
        // Mostrar mensaje de error
          $('#result-rif').fadeIn(1000).html('Introduce RIF válido');
        return;
    }
    var dataString = 'rif='+rif;            
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/php/maestros/chequear_proveedor_existente.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
          // Mensaje de éxito o error
          let resText;
          if(data == '0') {
              // Se puede continuar
              resText = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>¡Rif disponible!</strong></div>';
              activaDesactiva(true);
          } else {
              // Error, ¡ya existe!
              resText = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Rif ya está registrado.</strong></div>';
          }
          $('#result-rif').fadeIn(1000).html(resText);
        }
    });
  });
  // Insertar registro
  $('#registro-rif').submit(function(e) {
      // Cancelar proceso formulario
      e.preventDefault();
      // Realizas validaciones necesarias
      // Aquí pones tu petición AJAX para insertar
      // Si la petición fue exitosa
      // Borras todos los campos y activas solo RIF
      limpia();
  });
});

function limpia() {
    $('#result-rif').html('').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#registro-rif :input').each(function() {
        let item = this;
        // Limpias solo campos que no son botón
        if(item.type != 'button') {
            item.value = '';
        }
    });
    // Dejas listo para insertar nuevo registro
    activaDesactiva(true);
}

// Verdadero para deshabilitar, falso para habilitar
function activaDesactiva(activa) {
    $('#registro-rif :input').each(function() {
        let item = this;
        if(item.name == 'Cancelar') {
            // Este no se debe modificar
        } else if(item.id == 'rif_prov' || item.id == 'validar-rif') {
                // RIF y Validar RIF, contrarios al resto de elementos
                item.disabled = !activa;
        } else {
                item.disabled = activa;
        }
    });;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
     <div class="form-control page-header col-md-6 mx-auto text-center">
          <!--<div class="row" col>-->
          <h4>Módulo Proveedores<small> - Registro de Proveedores </small></h4>
       </div>
      
      <div class="container">
        <!--<h2>Módulo de Registro de Cobranza</h2>-->
      <br>        
        <form action="/php/maestros/pagina_insertar_proveedor.php" name="Aceptar" method="post" id="registro-rif">
            <div class="row">
              <!--form action="#" method="post"> Este form sobra -->
                <div class="col-md-3">          
                  <label for="rif_prov">RIF ó Cédula:</label>
                       <div class="col">
                          <input class="form-control" placeholder="RIF ó Cédula" name="rif_prov" id="rif_prov">
                          <button class="btn btn-success col-md-4 col-sm-1" id="validar-rif">Validar RIF</button>
                          <p class="help-block">Introducir (J) ó (V) seguido de números, sin guión</p>                          
                       </div>
                       <div id="result-rif"></div>                       
                </div>
              <!-- /form> Este cierre sobra -->                           
              <div class="col-md-9">
                  <label for="Nombre">Nombre: </label>
                        <div class="col"> 
                            <input class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" required>
                        </div>
              </div>
            </div>
              <div class="row">                                    
                   <div class="col-md-12">      
                     <label for="direccion">Dirección</label>
                        <div class="col">
                          <textarea class="form-control" id="direccion"  placeholder="Dirección" name="direccion" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                   </div>
              </div>   
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-4">      
                     <label for="estado">Estado / Provincia</label>
                        <div class="col">
                            <input class="form-control" id="estado" placeholder="Estado" name="estado" required>
                        </div>
                   </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">      
                   <label for="municipio">Municipio</label>
                      <div class="col">
                          <input class="form-control" id="municipio" placeholder="Municipio" name="municipio" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">      
                   <label for="sector">Sector / Urbanización / Barrio</label>
                      <div class="col">
                          <input class="form-control" id="sector" placeholder="Sector" name="sector" required>
                      </div>
                  </div>                  
              </div>
              <div class="row">                                    
                   <div class="col-md-6">      
                     <label for="telefono">Teléfonos</label>
                        <div class="col">
                            <input class="form-control" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" name="telefono" required>
                        </div>
                   </div>                   
                   <div class="col-md-6">      
                     <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <div class="col">
                            <input class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
                        </div>
                   </div>
              </div>
              <br>
             <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-1">                 
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-md-4 col-sm-1" name="Aceptar">Aceptar</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-md-4 col-sm-1" name="Cancelar" onClick="location.href='/index.php'">Salir</button>
                   </div>
              </div>
        </form>       
        </div>
```

En PHP solo devuelves el resultado de contar registros:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['rif'])) {        
    sleep(1);
    $rif  = strip_tags($_POST['rif']);
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= "/php/reportes/estado_de_cuenta/db/accesoDB.php";
    require_once($path);
    $pdo = AccesoDB::getConnectionPDO();            
    $stmt=$pdo->prepare("SELECT rif FROM proveedores WHERE rif=:rif");
    $stmt->execute(array(':rif'=>$rif));
    // Mostrar solo la cantidad de registros encontrados
    echo $stmt->rowCount();
} else {
    // RIF no está presente, no se puede insertar
    echo 1;
}
```